# Different character set command line vs Workbench vs Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

Problem with russian letters.
In mysql in windows 7 command line with next character set configuration:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                            |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                           |
| character_set_connection | latin1                           |
| character_set_database   | utf8                             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                           |
| character_set_results    | latin1                           |
| character_set_server     | latin1                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                             |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

and

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

all fine and i get something like this:

```
+------------------+
| name             |
+------------------+
| СТАНДАРТ+        |
| VIP тариф        |
| БАЗОВЫЙ 30       |
| БИЗНЕС 512       |
```

but with this configuration in MySQL Workbench get this:

```
��������+
VIP �����
������� 30
```

and in java application in Eclipse console or windows  prompt:

```
????????+
VIP ?????
??????? 30
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In java problem solved by get `ResultSet` string end get from it bytes in `ISO-8859-1`. After that create `new String` from bytes.

```
new String(rs.getString(1).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Comment: -1 This code will break on a Windows system with a different default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use Unicode (UTF-8 encoding) everywhere:

- When connecting to MySQL
- In the project settings in Eclipse
- In the preferences of MySQL Workbench

Also make sure you have fonts installed which support Unicode and you have configured your applications to use those fonts (the default fonts should be fine; if you changed the fonts, then reset the preferences).

Comment: all options in Eclipse and Workbench are default!

Comment: Default is usually wrong. Default is OK if you write code for yourself that you never share with anyone else in the world. As soon as you write code that will run on different systems (like one with a different default encoding), then the default will break.